# Dropdown list pupup lightbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a dropdown list that when any option is selected, it automatically opens selected option's URL location in a lightbox.

I don't know if this is possible, hoping to find help here
I am using fancybox and have been trying with the following

```
<select id="my_selection">
<option value="x" href="iframe.html">value 1</option>
<option value="y" href="iframe.html">value 2</option>
</select>
<script>document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');}</script>
```